# Telnet Process Continues after Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, telnet

I am running the following script

```
#! /bin/bash
HOSTLIST="192.168.0.5 192.168.22.1"
DELAY=3
stty echo
exec 4>&1
for HOST in $HOSTLIST ; do
   telnet $HOST 135 | grep Connected  & pid=$!
   echo "Checking $HOST"
   sleep $DELAY
   kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null
done
```

However, when it finishes, the Telnet connections are still being attempted in the background which spams annoying "telnet: unable to connect" errors randomly for the next few moments. I tried adding killing the process to stop this but it still does it. Am I doing something wrong for killing the process?

Also I have to use telnet, can't use netcat or nmap.

Comment: don't you have to "type" something like `quit` or `exit` to "close" the telnet connection (been a long time since I had to mess with that). Good luck!

Comment: Correct, though I assumed if I killed the process then it would close the connection. Though it seems like even killing the process doesn't stop it from attempting to connect :/

Comment: the `&` is definitely causing your problems (which I understand of course is major feature of what you're trying to accomplish). But to get a handle on what is happening, turn on shell debugging with `set -x`, remove the the `&` and then see what happens. Then you maybe able to think of an appropriate addition to your code. Good luck.

Comment: you might get something useful from this telnet question.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172917/passing-special-characters-into-telnet-unix  ... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The pid you are trying to kill is the pid of the grep since `$!` is the pid of the *most recently* executed background command. If you hadn't thrown away stderr when trying to kill it might have provided some clue...

BTW, `kill -9` is a serious code smell. Any well behaved process can be killed by at least one of the `-INT`, `-HUP`, `-TERM` or `-QUIT` signals. You should never need to `kill -KILL`. It's bad because it doesn't give the process opportunity to clean up its mess.