# Passing Special Characters into telnet Unix

Tags: unix, ksh, telnet, mime

I use the following command to send SMS messages through SMS Adapters:

```
telnet localhost 0000 <<-EOF 
helo x
MAIL FROM: Test
RCPT TO: 447999999999
DATA

Test £1234
.
logout
quit
EOF
```

However when ever I get the Message through it will be in the format:

```
Test ?£1234
```

Appending the ? to the front of the £ symbol, I have tried investigating a few methods including MIME however not quite sure how they can be implemented.

Any ideas on how I can stop and allow the successful passthroughs of £

Comment: you've got a double-whammy. you're dumping unicode chars into an email system, and then that email will get shoved into an SMS message. you need to double-encode your text so it'll get through the email stage into a format that'll be acceptable to the sms system.

Comment: @MarcB How would you implement this? Or have you got an example in which i can look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried encoding the message first?  You can do this using base64 in UTF-8 charset:-
e.g.
Convert:
    msg="£1234"
To:
    msg="wqMxMjM0"

NOTE:Try testing encoding/decoding using the online converter - https://www.base64encode.org/

Once you have encoded your text you can send the message via telnet by adding the MIME details after the DATA command in telnet by specifying MIME types, example script below:-

```
telnet localhost 0000 <<-EOF 
helo x
MAIL FROM: Test
RCPT TO: 447999999999
DATA
Subject: Test
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

${msg}
.
logout
quit
EOF
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: if someone use #expect - use this - send "Content-Type: text/html; charset='UTF-8'; Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64;"; - thx for direction @Bexxy

Answer (score 1):

In some installations, telnet is not 8-bit clean by default (It does not recognize 8-bit character encodings such as Unicode). In order to be able to send Unicode keystrokes to the remote host, you need to set telnet into "outbinary" mode. There are two ways to do this:

`$ telnet -L <host>`

and

`$ telnet`

`telnet> set outbinary`

`telnet> open <host>`

[Source](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unicode-HOWTO-4.html)

Comment: `telnet -L localhost ${PORT} <<-EOF > "${TMP_DIR}/telnet_result.txt"
  helo x
  MAIL FROM: ${FROM}
  RCPT TO: ${MSISDN}
  DATA
  
  $SMS_MESSAGE
  .
  logout
  quit
 EOF` I tried implementing this however no luck still passing through incorrectly, also tried the set outbinary in the EOF segment of the command

Comment: What is you're configuration (Windows/Linux/OS X) ? and How are you running your command (Putty, command line...)?

Comment: Unix Solaris 10, and its a ksh script

Comment: Ok! So if the encoding charset of your file `telenet_result.txt` is fixed you can just use iconv command (example : `iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 ./telnet_result.txt`). If it is not fixed you will have to write an "Encoding Sniffer" to determine the encoding charset.

Comment: The telnet_result.txt is just a file to handle output, nothing to do with the telnet command, good idea though.

Comment: @Pintouch strictly speaking, Unicode is not an 8-bit character encoding... The Unicode code set (or certain subsets of it) can be encoded using one of several different multi-byte encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.). ISO 8859-* would be better examples of an 8-bit character encoding...

Comment: @twalberg your right! I just give an example of iconv command.